# Setting field 'InputMask' properties programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access, properties, field

I have an Access database divided into front and back ends.

I need to modify the value of a property associated to one of the fields in a table programmatically. I do remember achieving something similar years ago, but that was for forms.

It seems that the properties of a table can only be set at design time; any attempt to modify the values using code (`myField.Properties("InputMask").Value = "000000"`) causes an error.

All in all, there are about 40 or 50 tables in a batch of roughly 80 that have a particular *type* of field that has to be changed, so I'd rather do this using code than manually. Could anyone suggest a method for doing this using VBA, please?

Presently I've looked at dropping and recreating the field using `CurrentDb.Execute sqlString`, but I'd like to retain the `InputMask` property if at all possible.

The original database is a 2002/3 format, but I'm editing this in Access 2010.

Comment: What error did you get with this code?

Comment: @HansUp: Yes - the `InputMask` has already been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following code to work. It will change the InputMask of the specified Table and Field....

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Test_It()
Dim WGD

    WGD = Resize_And_AddInputMask("Table3", "SomeNbr")

End Sub

' Modified version of code found at: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1708626
Public Function Resize_And_AddInputMask(ByVal someTableName As String, ByVal someZCField As String)

Dim db  As DAO.Database
Dim td  As DAO.TableDef
Dim fd  As DAO.Field
Dim prp As DAO.Property

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set td = db.TableDefs(someTableName)
    Set fd = td.Fields(someZCField)
    fd.Properties("InputMask") = "000099"
    fd.Properties.Refresh
    db.TableDefs.Refresh

    Set prp = Nothing
    Set fd = Nothing
    Set td = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Wayne.  I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: That was bizarre.  I read somewhere, in my roving, that directly setting the `InputMask` using VBA would cause an error, hence the weirdness in my question (@Andre). This worked perfectly. I had already figured out the resizing bit (using SQL against the database object). The main things that I had missed (and confused the issue further) were the `Fields.Refresh` and `TableDefs.Refresh` methods, and setting a separate object with `CurrentDb`.